# Window service throws a type initializer error

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm not sure what is happening with this app. It worked fine then one day it stopped working. I've tried to eliminate individual elements in the code but as soon as I added a few enums (see code below) it broke - so I removed them but this did not reverse the issue. Then I started from a brand new win service (using VS2010 and VS2008), adding class level vars and once again after adding enums the service would not start.

Here is the code and I was wondering if someone can help me out. I really appreciate it.

```
using _Mail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Uploader
{

public partial class _UploaderService : ServiceBase
{
    private static string smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
    private static string sendTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendTo"];
    private static string sendFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendFrom"];
    private static string portalURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portalURL"];
    private static string imageListFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageListFolder"];
    private static string remFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["remoteFolder"];
    private static string sourceFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceFileName"];
    private static string remoteDriveLetter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["remoteDriveLetter"];
    private static string remoteShareName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["remoteShareName"];
    private static string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"];
    private static string userPwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userPwd"];
    private static string statusMessage;
    private static string[] files;

    private static SPWeb _Web = new SPSite(portalURL).OpenWeb();
    private static NETRESOURCE res = new NETRESOURCE();

    public enum ResourceScope
    {
        RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 1,
        RESOURCE_GLOBALNET,
        RESOURCE_REMEMBERED,
        RESOURCE_RECENT,
        RESOURCE_CONTEXT
    };
    public enum ResourceType
    {
        RESOURCETYPE_ANY,
        RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
        RESOURCETYPE_PRINT,
        RESOURCETYPE_RESERVED
    };
    public enum ResourceUsage
    {
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_NOLOCALDEVICE = 0x00000004,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_SIBLING = 0x00000008,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED = 0x00000010
    };
    public enum ResourceDisplayType
    {
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NETWORK,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_ROOT,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHAREADMIN,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DIRECTORY,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_TREE,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NDSCONTAINER
    };
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct NETRESOURCE
    {
        public ResourceScope dwScope;
        public ResourceType dwType;
        public ResourceDisplayType dwDisplayType;
        public ResourceUsage dwUsage;
        public string lpLocalName;
        public string lpRemoteName;
        public string lpComment;
        public string lpProvider;
    };

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    public static extern int WNetAddConnection2(ref NETRESOURCE
    netResource, string password, string username, int flags);

    public cisf_UploaderService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        try
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fsWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Created);

            DisconnectDrive(remoteDriveLetter);
            res.dwType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
            res.lpLocalName = remoteDriveLetter;
            res.lpRemoteName = remoteShareName;
            int stat = WNetAddConnection2(ref res, null, null, 0);
            statusMessage += "Map Network Drive status - " + stat + ".";

            //MapDrive();

            CleanUp();
            fsWatcher.Path = remFolder;
            fsWatcher.Filter = sourceFileName;
            fsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            WriteException(ex1,"Ex1");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    static void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        statusMessage += "\nNew PowerPoint file detected in directory.";

        ConvetToJpegs();
        AcquireFiles();
        CleanUp();
        DisconnectDrive(remoteDriveLetter);

        statusMessage += "\nOperation sucessfuly completed.";

        EventLog.WriteEntry("Conversion Service Status", statusMessage, EventLogEntryType.Information);

    }

    protected static void ConvetToJpegs()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Presentation pptPresentation = null;

        try
        {
            pptPresentation = app.Presentations.Open(remFolder + sourceFileName, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            pptPresentation.SaveAs(remFolder + ".", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            WriteException(ex2, "Ex2");
        }
        finally
        {
            pptPresentation.Close();
            statusMessage += "\nFile conversion completed.";
        }
    }

    protected static void AcquireFiles()
    {
        files = null;

        try
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(remFolder, "*.jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex3)
        {
            WriteException(ex3, "Ex3");
        }
        finally
        {
            statusMessage += "\nFiles acquired.";
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                DeleteOldSlides();
            }
        }
    }

    protected static void DeleteOldSlides()
    {
        SPList imagesLibrary = _Web.Lists[imageListFolder];
        _Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        try
        {
            while (imagesLibrary.Items.Count > 1)
            {
                imagesLibrary.Items[imagesLibrary.Items.Count - 1].File.Delete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex4)
        {
            WriteException(ex4, "Ex4");
        }
        finally
        {
            statusMessage += "\nOld slides deleted.";
            UploadToSharePoint();
        }
    }

    protected static void UploadToSharePoint()
    {
        _Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        FileStream fs = null;
        string fileName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {

                fileName = file.Split(@"\".ToCharArray())[1].ToLower();
                fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
                _Web.Files.Add(imageListFolder + "/" + fileName, fs, true);
                fileName = string.Empty;
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex5)
        {
            WriteException(ex5, fileName);
        }
        finally
        {
            statusMessage += "\nFiles uploaded to SharePoint.";
            _Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }

    protected static void CleanUp()
    {
        string[] path = Directory.GetFiles(remFolder, "*.jpg");
        string[] path1 = Directory.GetFiles(remFolder, "*.pptx");

        try
        {
            foreach (string tempfiles in path1)
            {
                if (path != null)
                {
                    File.Delete(tempfiles);
                }
            }
            foreach (string tempfiles in path)
            {
                if (path != null)
                {
                    File.Delete(tempfiles);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex6)
        {
            WriteException(ex6, "Ex6");
        }
        finally
        {
            statusMessage += "\nFiles deleted from temporary directory " + remoteShareName ;
        }
    }

    //public static bool MapDrive() 
    //{ 
    //    bool ReturnValue = false;
    //    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(remoteDriveLetter + ":\\")) 
    //    {
    //        DisconnectDrive(remoteDriveLetter); 
    //    } 
    //    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
    //    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
    //    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
    //    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
    //    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
    //    p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
    //    p.StartInfo.Arguments = " use " + remoteDriveLetter + ": " + remoteShareName + " " + userPwd + " /user:" + userName; 
    //    p.Start(); 
    //    p.WaitForExit(); 
    //    string ErrorMessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); 
    //    string OuputMessage = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
    //    if (ErrorMessage.Length > 0) 
    //    { 
    //        throw new Exception("Error:" + ErrorMessage); 
    //    } else { ReturnValue = true; } return ReturnValue; }

    protected static void DisconnectDrive(string DriveLetter)
    {
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        try
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " use " + "Z" + ": /DELETE";
            p.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex7)
        {
            WriteException(ex7, "Ex7");
        }
        finally
        {
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    public static void WriteException(Exception ex, string source)
    {
        string err = "Uploader Error" +
                     "\n\nError Message from method " + source + ": " + ex.Message.ToString() +
                     "\n\nStack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace.ToString() + "\n";
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Conversion Service", err, EventLogEntryType.Warning);

        _Mail sendEmail = new _Mail();
        sendEmail.SMTPServer = smtpServer;
        sendEmail.MailTo = sendTo;
        sendEmail.MailFrom = sendFrom;
        sendEmail.MailSubject = "Uploader Error";
        sendEmail.MailBody = err;
        sendEmail.Send();
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact message, and what does InnerException say?

Comment: "Stoped working" is not very helpful... Are any exceptions thrown and if so which and what is the error message? Why don't you debugg line by line and see where it throws an exception?

Comment: @MarcGravell I always forget about the InnerException

Comment: Thanks for all your replys. @MarcGravel - On the server where I want this to reside the service will not start: Could not start Uploader service on Local Compouter. On a dev box with VS2010 debugger I get: "The type initialization for Uploader threw an exception" - no more detail.

Comment: @kzen: I don't know what happened. Initially the service would require two attempts to start but would start. The following morning it was stopped and would not start. (security admins usually run pathes overnight). The server event log entry reads: "EventType clr20r3, P1 slebbuploaderservice.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4e8cd395, P4 slebbuploaderservice, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 4e8cd395, P7 4, P8 7, P9 system.typeinitialization, P10 NIL." which I found all sorts of post but nothing helpful.

Comment: @Risho, just debugg it on the dev box and try to find the line of code that throws an exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type Initializer error means that the type couldn't be created. This happens before the call to the constructor when the CLR initialized all the static fields. Since your initialization does something more than call a private constructor or set a literal value you're opening yourself up to difficult to debug problems

In this case its likely do to a problem with one of your AppSettings keys

e.g.

```
private static string smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
private static string sendTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendTo"];
...
```

This looks suspicious as well.

```
private static SPWeb _Web = new SPSite(portalURL).OpenWeb();
private static NETRESOURCE res = new NETRESOURCE();
```

Instead do what you need to do in the constructor. You might also want to add a helper method so that way you can raise a better exception (or instead you could as Marc Gravel comments just look at the Inner Exception)

For example

```
 private string safeGetAppSetting(string key)
 {

   try 
   { 
         return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
   }
   catch(ConfigurationErrorsException)
   {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("key {0} is missing or misconfigured", key);
   }
 }




public cisf_UploaderService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    smtpServer = safeGetAppSetting("smtpServer");
}
```

**Update** In hindsight adding Debugger.Launch() to Program.Main() as kzen mentioned may be worthwhile. If its not a local dev machine that's the issue adding some additional logging at the root may help as well.

```
        try
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new SampleWindowsService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string SourceName = "YourService.ExceptionLog";
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(SourceName))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(SourceName, "Application");
            }

            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
            eventLog.Source = SourceName;
            string message = "";
            if (ex.InnerException  != null)
                string message = string.Format("Exception: {0} \n\nStack: {1} \n\nInnerException: {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException.Message);
            else
                string message = string.Format("Exception: {0} \n\nStack: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            eventLog.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
```

Comment: ok, I'm a web developer and this is my first windows app: so how do you get to the inner exception here.

Comment: It should be logged with original exception, in the eventlog

Comment: I've been doing different things, but wanted to revisit this issue. I have placed the delaration in the constructor as you suggested bur still getting the same error as the service fails to start.  "EventType clr20r3, P1 slebbuploaderservice.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4e8cd395, P4 slebbuploaderservice, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 4e8cd395, P7 4, P8 7, P9 system.typeinitialization, P10 NIL."

Comment: that's a pretty unhelpful error. I've added some logging logic that may help you

Answer (score 0):

Make `Debugger.Launch();` the first line of your code, start your service and debugg line by line until you find exactly what line of code throws the exception...

Comment: Normally I'd agree with this. Sadly type initialization isn't super deterministic. The exception may occur before a call `Debugger.Launch()` even if you put it in `Program.Main()`